# Complex series radius convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series

How to find the values for which $z$ converges, $z\in\mathbb{C}$, in the serie
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+|z|^{2})^{n}}$$
I know I have to use the convergence radius expression, but what I suppose to do here? I mean,
as 
$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$
what is $a_{n}$ in this case?

Comment: The formula you are writing is for $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n z^n$. You maybe able to rewrite your series into this form, but there is an easier way: Are you familiar with the ratio test?

Comment: Not so much haha @Braindead

Comment: The following link has some nice examples. http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/radcon/radcon02/radcon02.html

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment, it should say $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ (or more appropriately for this case: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n |z|^n$, since your expression depends on $|z|$ and not so much on $z$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

For which values of $y$ does

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y^n
$$

converge?

Now let

$$
y = \frac{1}{1+|z|^2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** This is not really a question about complex numbers. Think **geometric series**.

For the question *as it stands now*, you do not have to use the convergence radius expression. But to answer your question about $a_n$, if you will use the **Ratio Test** then you should use $a_n=\frac{1}{(1+|z|^2)^n}$. Note that our series is not a power series in the usual sense. So formulas you may remember about radius of convergence need not apply.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I think your hint is a bit confusing for the questioner, since your "formula" for $a_n$ does not fit into the formula for Radius of convergence that user162441 put up.

Comment: Thank you, I have reworded. The warning I had given about it not being a power series was probably too gnomic.